# render partials in ajax call in sails js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to render a partial using ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  //some code
  success: function(response){
    data = response.data;
    body = "<%- partial ('../partial/thread.ejs', {thread: thread}) %>";
    $('.modal-body').html(data);
    $('.modal').show();
  }
});
```

result of this code is pop up modal with the text "<%- partial ('../partial/thread.ejs', {thread: thread}) %>". it does not render the relevant partial in the page. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to render a server side tag on the client side? Havent used sails.js but surely it gets rendered server side (i.e. before page load)

Comment: I just need to use the response data from the ajax call and use it in the partial. Isn't there any way to do this ?

Comment: what I mean is that partial() is a method of the server side code/lib, not jquery. According to the ejs docs you'd use something like this to render is clientside var something = new EJS({url: '../partial/thread.ejs'}).render(data)

Answer (score 0):

Before do this , you can use library such as jquery and you can use $.ajax method or .load() method

for example

```
function loadContent(url){
    $('#your_content').load(url)
}

// implementation in client side

loadContent('/your_route')
```

you cannot get direct to file_name_views.ejs , but you must create route and call this route that response partial view.

Hopefully can help you

Answer (score 0):

#### Client side js

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some_url',
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

//Dont forget to use `dataType: 'script'` option. Its very important.

#### Controller

```
return res.render('some_ejs_file.ejs', {layout: false});
```

#### some_ejs_file.ejs

```
$('SELECTOR').html(`<%- partial ('A_PARTIAL') %>`);
console.log('Its good to see working :)')
```